# Символ перевода строки PHP_EOL

Tags: php

Привет.Прочитал, что эта константа обеспечивает перевод строки для разных ОС.
Почему тогда в примере

```
 <?php echo 'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO' ?>
```

вместо переводов строк появляются только пробелы? 
Какая область ее применения?
Только добавление `header("Content-type: text/plain");` помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему вы смотрите через браузер. В код страницы посмотрите там будет перевод строки. А для браузера надо ставить

[image]

Comment: проверил в файлы идет запись с переводом строчки.Не подскажите как идет запись в БД?

Comment: перефразируйте пожалуйста вопрос. т.к. если запись символа PHP_EOL то скорее всего 0 либо null но может и \r\n не проверял

Comment: вот эту переменную $str='TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'   вставить в БД.

Comment: да нормально закидает, как перевод строки

Comment: @koza4ok, а проверить самостоятельно уже никак?

Comment: Спасибо binliz

Answer (score 3):

Так лучше понятно:

```
<?php 
 echo 'TOO'.'TOO'.'TOO'."</br>";
 echo 'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO';
 echo "<pre>".'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'."</pre>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP_EOL может в себе содержать только два значения либо `\r\n` для windows платформ либо `\n` для остальных. Раньше - до версии 5.4 была и третье возможное значение `\r` для Mac OSX, но в версиях по старше это уже не актуально.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать nl2br()

```
<?php echo nl2br('TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO'.PHP_EOL.'TOO');
```